# How to connect using SSL in Sequel Pro?

Tags: mysql, ssl, sequelpro

I've installed MySQL 8.0.17 on a Mac using `brew install mysql` and would like to connect to a local database using SSL. From https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-encrypted-connections.html, it seems that I need the files in this snippet:

[image]

I found these files in `/usr/local/var/mysql` and entered them as `Key File`, `Certificate`, and `CA Cert` in Sequel Pro. However, I get an

> SSL connection error: ASN: bad other signature confirmation

as shown in the screenshot below.

[image]

I've tried verifying the certificate using `openssl` and it seems to be OK:

```
/u/l/v/mysql> 
openssl verify -CAfile ca.pem client-cert.pem
client-cert.pem: OK
```

Any idea how I can overcome this error and connect to the database using SSL?

Comment: Using TLS to connect to 127.0.0.1 is not really useful, you won't gain any more security as it is already a purely local traffic (not leaving the host). Except if this is for debugging and later trying remotely. Also it would help if you show the content of both certificates, and did you try with another one?